# C++ How to store pointer of function?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Here is my code:

```
class Opcodes {
public:
    Opcodes() = default;
    virtual ~Opcodes() = default;
    virtual void Initialize() = 0;
    virtual void ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(std::vector<std::byte>& data)) = 0;
    class PacketHandler{
    public:
        PacketHandler() = default;
        ServerOpcode serverOpcode;
        std::vector<std::byte> data;
        void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(std::vector<std::byte>& data);
        void Run();
    private:
        WorldSession* _session;
    };

protected:
    PacketHandler* opcodeHandler[NUM_MSG_TYPES];
};
```

Let's focus on this function:

```
void ValidateAndSetServerOpcode(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(std::vector<std::byte>& data))
```

How can I store `void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(std::vector<std::byte>& data)` which is the second parameter of `ValidateAndSetServerOpcode` in a pointer member inside `PacketHandler` ?

I tried `void(WorldSession::*HandlerFunction)(std::vector<std::byte>& data);` but that is not the correct approach.

Here is how I try to assign it inside `ValidateAndSetServerOpcode`:

```
opcodeHandler[serverOpcode]->HandlerFunction = HandlerFunction;
```

However it does not work. I get crash when I try to assign like that.

Is it even possible and if so how ?

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct? (It gets far more readable if you introduce a type alias, though.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: If you want to "store" a function, then use `std::function`. You can even bind a lambda to it, which is nice.

Comment: Are you going out of bounds with `serverOpcode`? What have you learned from using your debugger?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Looks like maybe you're making an array of pointers (the `opcodeHandler` variable), but not assigning anything to those pointers, and then accessing a member of the pointer anyway. The fact it's a function pointer you're using at the right hand side is a red herring.

Comment: Let me put it another way. In C++ if you do `int* x[3]` then `*(x[1]) = 2` you'll get a crash. Just because you have an array of pointers doesn't mean those pointers point to anything, unless you set it up first. (Apologies if that's not actually your problem, but since you don't have a complete example all I can do is guess.)

Comment: @ArthurTacca that was the case! Problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The definition for the pointer to function is corrrect, but **maybe you don't initialize the pointer that you use**.

In any case, your approch is a `C` approch, or even a `C++` approch before the `C++11 standard`.
From `C++11 standard` is better to use the [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function#:%7E:text=Instances%20of%20std%3A%3Afunction,target%20of%20std%3A%3Afunction%20.) provided by the standard library, that give the possibility also to assign a lambda function.